# How to replace text in label with an image in kivy?

Tags: python, image, label, kivy

Is it possible to replace text in label with an image in kivy?

I have a label containing a text but i want to replace the text with an image.

Is this possible in kivy?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is technically yes, but this isn't something exposed by the label api so you'd have to mess about doing stuff manually. It would probably be a better idea to put an Image on top of (or behind) the Label, and use this to display the imgae when necessary.